# Jetty JDBCLoginService doesn't pick up password changes?

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, forms-authentication

I'm successfully using the Jetty `JDBCLoginService` for FORM authentication (just as described in the [Jetty configuring security authentication page](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-security-authentication.html)).

The first time a user logs in the `JDBCLoginService` caches the user password details (if you follow the logic through from [`JDBCLoginService.loadUser(String)`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/8c58a9a/jetty-security/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/security/JDBCLoginService.java#L264) you pretty quickly get to the user identity being cached in the [`MappedLoginService._users` map](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/8c58a9a/jetty-security/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/security/MappedLoginService.java#L199)).

However nothing ever invalidates this cache - even if the user logs out the old details stay there forever.

In my webapp I've provided my own user settings servlet that allows user's to change their password. This interacts with the database completely independently of `JDBCLoginService` so obviously changes it makes are not picked up by the `JDBCLoginService`.

I can't see any obvious way for the webapp to signal such changes to the login service. I'm going to try subclassing `JDBCLoginService` and overriding [`MappedLoginService.logout(UserIdentity)`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/8c58a9a/jetty-security/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/security/MappedLoginService.java#L138) to always remove the user from the cache on logout so that any password change is picked up when they next login.

But changing one's password is fairly normal so I'm surprised I need to change the standard behavior - should I be handling things differently? Or using e.g. a more advanced library that builds on `JDBCLoginService`?

Comment: I would wager that a majority of people prefer not to rely on container-specific authentication/authorization mechanisms.  I believe most people use http://shiro.apache.org/index.html or http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/, personally I prefer Shiro

Comment: I agree - not using Shiro and trying to bake something myself was probably an act of idiocy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of Jetty is this?  The `9.2.6` Javadocs for `JDBCLoginService` say this:

> HashMapped User Realm with JDBC as data source. JDBCLoginService extends HashULoginService and adds a method to fetch user information from database. The login() method checks the inherited Map for the user. If the user is not found, it will fetch details from the database and populate the inherited Map. It then calls the superclass login() method to perform the actual authentication. Periodically (controlled by configuration parameter), internal hashes are cleared. Caching can be disabled by setting cache refresh interval to zero. Uses one database connection that is initialized at startup. Reconnect on failures. authenticate() is 'synchronized'. An example properties file for configuration is in $JETTY_HOME/etc/jdbcRealm.properties

Which means you can control the frequency at which the cache is invalidated, or disable caching altogether.

But see my comment's above, you may prefer to use a more robust authentication/authorization setup with Shiro or Spring Security (doesn't necessarily require Spring)

Comment: It's always embarrassing being pointed at the documentation :) You're right - if I set `cachetime = 0` in the config properties file for the `JDBCLoginService` then things aren't cached and any changes are picked up at login.

Comment: Interestingly the javadoc is wrong - `JDBCLoginService` isn't a subclass of `HashLoginService` (and never was), rather both are subclasses of `MappedLoginService`. And the current behavior, if `cacheTime` is zero, in `JDBCLoginService.login(String, Object)` seems a bit *odd* - it doesn't just discard of the details for the user logging in (and hence force a refetch), it discards all cached user details. So each time *anyone* logs in all other users will incur a hit the next time they access a page (as the cache is used for role lookup etc. for each page access, not just for login).

Comment: @GeorgeHawkins the javadoc error had me curious, so I traced JDBCLoginService back 204 revisions (even back into pre-eclipse Jetty at svn.codehaus.org).  It truly [never was a subclass of HashLoginService](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/da627b843fe81fa0fe52a046c1be8595630e9ae7/jetty-security/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/security/JDBCLoginService.java).

Answer (score 0):

On 9.4.x this feature seems to be removed:

https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/commit/81b2a6a4de22ebb3d3e1c857e686bccbfd636c4d

https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/commit/81b2a6a4de22ebb3d3e1c857e686bccbfd636c4d#diff-4a6398c38fa91cfa934acb61be7e7e21100196b7c26fde7f403a9df3a0d8ee2c